# Visibility of byline in folder view in collages for plone 3.3.1

Tags: plone

I'm currently in the process of setting up my plone site to show expiration dates for content items in folders. This is part of a process to keep track of old files and documents on our intranet.

I have already altered my "folder listing" to show the expiration date if there is one (or say there isn't if there is no such date) which works as I expected. Unfortunately I cannot seem to replicate this with one of my addons.

I am currently using an addon called collage (version 1.2.3) which basically allows us to have a combination of different sorts of content as main-pages. I'm not quite sure what it is about collages that does this but when they show the contents of folders they only seem to show the title and description.

Previously this was fine but now I want to show the expiration date from the byline. I've been searching through all the python files and views and I can't seem to find where it decides to cut off the byline but it does sound like it calls on the folder_listing file.

When I open up a page which uses a collage to show a folder and view the source the byline *is* there, but it doesn't show up in the final version for some reason.

If anyone knows collages or plone moderately well and has a thought about this I would greatly appreciate any insight.

As a reference, I altered my folder_list by including this underneath the entry for tal:modified:

```
<tal:expire condition="python: item_type != 'Event'">
    &mdash;
    <tal:mod tal:condition="python:toLocalizedTime(item_expire,long_format=1)" i18n:translate="box_when_expires">
      Expires on
    </tal:mod>
    <span tal:condition="not: python:toLocalizedTime(item_expire,long_format=1)">
      This item has no expiration date listed.
    </span>
    <span tal:replace="python:toLocalizedTime(item_expire,long_format=1)">
      August 16, 2001 at 23:35:59
    </span>
</tal:expire>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should look at **Collage CSS** Products/Collage/browser/templates/collage.css.dtml

There is the following instruction which hides documentByLine

```
#collage .collage-item .documentByLine {
    display: none;
}
```

I have overrided this rule to set `display: block;` in my own css.

Comment: Perfect, that's exactly what I was looking for, I don't know why I didn't think of looking in the css.